# Error with opening MDF file on a different computer - Error number 26

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a this frustrating problem, concerning error 26. My DB is a local `.MDF` file, next to the app itself and my program conncets to it, to retrieve data.

Now, on my computer it works fine, after building it of course, but when I installed it on 2 different computers, I get this error. I've installed .net framework 4.5 on these computers, but still, no go.

```
Dim connenctionstring As String = 
  "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\whmdf.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

This is my connection string, it works on my computer but on others it doesn't. What seems to be the problem? Perhaps, the data source? Maybe it's because they don't have SQL Server?
If that's the case, is there any SQL driver to make it run?

My software is now on a run-up stage before I publish it, and this thing is very frustrating...

Thanks.

Comment: To use the `AttachDbFileName=` feature, the computer this runs on **must have** SQL Server**EXPRESS** (and no other edition!) installed

Comment: You can only have one computer (or SQL Server instance) connected to any .MDF file. The first one to connect will lock the file so others cannot use it. If you need others to connect, they should connect to your SQL server instance and not the .mdf, (unless you are using clustering)

Comment: It's a local DB, it's next to the app itself and acts as a personal DB for that particular user and only for him. If I add a prerequisite to the istallation of MS SQL 2012 Native Client, will it work then?